# How to manage duplicates after cSplit(data, "text", ",", "long")?

Tags: r, duplicates

I'm validating a set of data and want to design visualisation without duplication. For example of the dataset,

```
ID       Date      Hashtags
49312   28/3/2019   #apple
49312   28/3/2019   #orange
49312   28/3/2019   #grape
49313   02/4/2019   #orange
49314   02/4/2019   #apple
```

When I calculate the total count of ID, it calculates as 5 instead of 3. How can I manage this type of data so it will group the ID?

When I used the script:-

```
newdata <- dataset [!duplicate(data$id)],
```

it removes the duplicate in `ID` and removing the Hashtags as well.

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicate `ID`s ? Try `df[!duplicated(df$ID), ]` by replacing `df` with your dataset name and if you want to count unique ID's you can do it by `length(unique(df$ID))` or `dplyr::n_distinct(df$ID)`

Comment: I do not think it is logic to remove the duplicate because the ID represents the different hashtags. I wondering if there possible way group similar ID.